# TYPO3 custom content inline elements

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

Is it possible to create a custom content element (type inline) where i can choose from the default typo3 elements (text with image, grids, html)?
At the moment i have an custom content with a new table an can insert my own element as a child.
I would like to give the editor the opprtunity to create an element like an tag and insert whatever he wants.

i have this code

```
 'parent_uid' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        '',
                        0,
                    ],
                ],
                'default' => 0,
                'foreign_table' => 'tt_content',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tt_content.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tt_content.sys_language_uid IN (-1, ###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###)',
            ],
        ],
        'parent_table' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
```

and this

```
$tabs = [
'k_custom_content_tab' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'Field label',
    'config' => [
        'appearance' => [
            'collapseAll' => '1',
            'enabledControls' => [
                'dragdrop' => '1',
            ],
            'levelLinksPosition' => 'bottom',
            'useSortable' => '1',
        ],
        'foreign_field' => 'parent_uid',
        'foreign_table' => 'k_custom_content_tab',
        'foreign_table_field' => 'parent_table',
        'maxitems' => '20',
        'minitems' => '1',
        'type' => 'inline',
    ],
],


\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    $tabs
);
```

Comment: Should be possible by changing `foreign_table`to 'tt_content'.

Comment: this doenst work. if i add this thenn i could add a normal content element and this will not be rendered over my template file

Comment: How are you rendering `k_custom_content_tab` in your template?

Comment: So, you want a tab container where to put several container elements (= content elements)?

Comment: thats right. it should look like you add a new content element on a typo3 page